# Can not access and change property of a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify a property of an object.

```
console.log(dataset); 
// -> This shows object with an 'ids' property, and it is an array with 7 elements.
```

But

```
console.log(dataset.ids); //shows an empty array
```

Please take a look at this image, it describles how 'dataset' look like: [weired js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnuDs.png)

Can you explain why?

Thank you!

Comment: can you share what your dataset look like?

Comment: can u please provide the object `dataset`

Comment: Yeah, I attached an image, please take a look at: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SnuDs.png

Comment: No, I mean can you share the output of `for ( var key in dataset) { console.log( 'key = ' + dataset[key] ); }`

Comment: @gurvinder372: It is too long to paste it here, please view it here: http://triankhachhang-t1.menard.vn/public/keys.txt

Comment: I modified your code a bit to log full objects, and the 6th line is 
    `key =  []`

Comment: @ThanhLoyal yes it is and it's normal as I explained better on my answer comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `dataset.ids` array isn't filled yet on the `init`.

Why?

When your open your panel from the Chrome console to inspect in details of `dataset`, Chrome console just recall a console log on the reference object.

At this time, the array is filled.

You should probably search a hook from your KanbanView object where you are sure this array is filled if you want to access it.

This console behavior could be confusing the first time when you face such case!

Comment: Then how can the first log show an 'ids' with 7 elements?
log(dataset)  <--- ids filled.
After that:
log(dataset.ids) <-ids not filled.

Comment: I just gave you the answers above... I'm pretty sure on the first console.log the array is also empty (you cannot see it cause the line is too long on the console and Chrome cut it). When you're unroll the console inspector, Chrome call a new console.log on the object reference (so AFTER every execution code)

Comment: Oh, you are right. I wrote `console.log(dataset.ids)` in a `setTimeout` and that shows a full array. Thank you.